# Cordova CLI 5.2.0 cannot change activity name from the default (MainActivity)

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Cordova CLI 5.2.0 which includes Cordova Android 4.1.1.

According to Cordova Android [release notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md), Cordova Android 4.0.0 included a new create option (--activity-name="ActivityName") as part of [CB-7827](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7827). However, using the new option appears to have no effect.  The activity name remains unchanged at the default MainActivity.

Surely, I must be doing something wrong...

$ cordova create testapp com.testappdomain TestApp --activity-name=TestApp

Interestingly enough, the bug remains open despite the release note mention and commit messages with the new code.